# How to install mac OS X ElCapitan on Windows 10

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I have window PC , it has 4 gb ram, intel i3 processor and 120 gb ssd.

When I am install mac osx on Windows 10 os, it gives the following error.

> Mac OS X is not supported with binary translation. To run Mac OS X you need a host on which VMware Player supports Intel VT-x or AMD-V.

For fixing this issue in BIOS setting Virtualisation technology or intel vt must be enable but I could not found these type of option in BIOS >>Advance option >> Advance >> cpu configuration.

Comment: First, know that what you are doing is not legal, but I assume you are doing for the good of all people. Second... your CPU probably doesn't support VT-x, you can check this in [http://ark.intel.com/]

Comment: I have already checked ,my CPU supported VT-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you downloaded and ran Unlocker on your machine?  You need to run this to patch your VMWare workstation application so that it will support OSX

http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/303311-workstation-1112-player-712-fusion-78-and-esxi-6-mac-os-x-unlocker-2/